# What does $x \sim X$ mean in probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, notation, definition

I just want to confirm what  $x \sim X$ mean in probability. What does the small $x$ and big $X$ represent? And can we replace $\sim$ with $=$.

Disclosure: I had read many probability textbooks from front to back such as Leon-Garcia and Papoulis, but never encountered this notation until I looked at some notes online.  I think this is a notation used in stastistics, because $\sim$ is not very informative in my view.

Comment: It would be helpful to give an example of this symbol being used in context.

Comment: I have seen the $\sim$ sign often in probability, but rarely if ever with a lower-case letter on the left-hand side. If you have really seen something like this I would _very_ much want to see an example with some context around it.

Comment: @DavidK hi, there is like entire fields in AI and machine learning dedicated to using arbitrary symbols like this https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.2661.pdf

Comment: @DavidK See also https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.00141.pdf

Comment: Ah, well, one thing about CS papers is they often bastardize mathematical notations, and one thing about papers in arxiv is there are no independent reviewers to send them back for revision repeatedly until the authors define their undefined symbols. But the use of $\sim$ at least seems to be intended the way it is explained in the answer below.

Comment: @DavidK hi, I've seen a more interesting example here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.10551.pdf, the author seems to have written in euqation 1, something like $(x, x^\prime) \sim p \otimes q_\theta$. Do you have any idea what this might mean?

Comment: Presumably $p\otimes q_\theta$ is a joint distribution of some kind, and $(x,x')$ is a random vector. Again it's like in the answer below, except you have a random vector instead of a single random number.

Comment: did you realize that is references the paper where it is defined,  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.02511.pdf

Comment: @DavidK Ok, so we are talking about $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$

Comment: @RHowe I think that paper may have introduced the notation but certainly didn't define it

Comment: have you ever read a scientific paper?  right above that it says Huang et al. go read huang et al, it's in the bibliography, I linked huang et al.  Its on page 2 of huang et al.

Comment: @RHowe Yes I have read a scientific paper before and no where did Huang et al. (which is by the way, has some same author as the other one) define what $p \otimes q_\theta$ mean.

Comment: it's the third paragraph of the second page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you would say something like the following

$$ X \sim \textrm{Uniform}(-1,1) \tag{1} $$

then $X$ is a random variable and it follows the uniform distribution with parameters $-1$ and $1$. Typically a uniform distribution is like this.

$$ f_{X}(x) =\begin{align}\begin{cases} \frac{1}{b-a} &  \textrm{ for } a \leq x \leq b \\ 0   &  \textrm{ everywhere else }  \end{cases} \end{align} \tag{2}$$

when with parameters $-1$ and $1$ we have

$$ f_{X}(x) =\begin{align}\begin{cases} \frac{1}{2} &  \textrm{ for } -1 \leq x \leq 1 \\ 0   &  \textrm{ everywhere else }  \end{cases} \end{align} \tag{3}$$

In other words, it is saying that $x$ is a random variable and following a distribution given by $X$ in your case, with a distribution function given by it. In other words, it is like the $=$ sign but typically it can refer to a family of functions.

### Edit:

If you read the paper in section $3$ on page $2$ it literally defines [things.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.2661.pdf)

> To learn the generator’s distribution $p_{g}$ over data x, we define a
>   prior on input noise variables $p_{z}(z)$,

It uses notation like this in $4$

> The generator G implicitly defines a probability distribution $p_{g}$ as
>   the distribution of the samples G(z) obtained when $z ∼ p_{z}$

...did you read the paper?

### Edits:

For the second part if you read the [paper,](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.02511.pdf) it is defined on page $2$.

> where $p$ is the distribution to learn and $q_{\theta}$ is the distribution
>   defined by the implicit generator. The expectation is minimized over a
>   parametrized class of functions

and you note that $\otimes$ is the tensor product.

Comment: But in their papers, $x$ is defined as data, and $p_g$ is distribution. Whereas in your answer, $X$ is a random variable, and $f_X(x)$ is the probability density function. Are you telling me that they mean the same thing? If so, why not written as the way you do (or in most probability textbooks like the ones I have read)? And what is a tensor product of distributions?

Comment: The third paragraph said, "where p is the distribution to learn and qθ is the distribution defined by the implicit generator." but it didn't say anything about $p \otimes q_\theta$.

Comment: as the other person noted, they bastardize the notation.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product . I am assuming this may actually be like a covariance matrix? but I don't know.

Comment: I don't know enough about the area my main point was to read the paper and search through the bibliography.

Comment: I don't know either, it was just some paper on Reddit that looks interesting but I couldn't get through due to the notation.

Comment: there is a book you could check out.  https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf